# Definition of holomorphic vector bundle using sheafs

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, sheaf-theory, holomorphic-bundles

Can somebody give me a general idea how to define a vector bundle of rank $N$ if we have a sheaf, which is locally given by $N$ holomorphic functions?

Comment: This previous question (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1594069/vector-bundle-as-locally-free-coherent-sheaves) might help

Comment: What does "locally given by $N$ holomorphic functions" mean? Do you know the sheaf is locally free?